# Changing value of second element in a tuple contained within a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples

i am having trouble changing the value of one of the elements in a list tuples.

```
 letterList = [('a', 0), ('b', 0), ('c', 0), ('d', 0), ('e', 0), ('f', 0), ('g', 0), ('h', 
 0), ('j', 0), ('k', 0), ('l', 0), ('m', 0), ('n', 0), ('o', 0), ('p', 0), ('q', 0), ('r',
 0), ('s', 0), ('t', 0), ('u', 0), ('v', 0), ('w', 0), ('x', 0), ('y', 0), ('z', 0)] 
 for m in message:
     letterList[m][0] += 1
```

When i use this i get the error that "list indices must be integers, not str". Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is `message`, and do you realise that tuples are immutable?

Comment: message is just a string of letters

Comment: And letters, as you are being told, aren't valid list indices. List indices are integers, starting with `0`. If you want e.g. `object['a']` to work, `object` is probably best as a dictionary. If you want `object['a'][0] += 1` to work, a dictionary of lists.

Comment: @user3369239 Can you please show us entire your code ?

Answer (score 6):

Tuples are immutable; you'll have to rebuild the whole tuple. However, *you don't have a mapping*, you'd have to search the whole list of letters each time:

```
for m in message:
    letterList = [(l, c + 1 if m == c else c) for l, c in letterList]
```

This is *very* inefficient; you cannot find the matching tuple otherwise. You'd be much better of using an actual dictionary.

That's what your code in the loop was (sort of) trying to do already; treat `letterList` as a dictionary; mapping individual characters to counts. But lists only take integers as indices; `0` is the first value, `1` is the second, and so on; `m` is a one-character string however, and that's not an acceptable index.

You can easily convert your `letterList` to a dictionary:

```
letterDict = dict(letterList)
```

then increment the values:

```
for m in message:
    letterDict[m] += 1
```

Note that there isn't a second index here.

However, in this case you *really* want to use a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object instead here:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(message)
```

Now `counts` contains a mapping from individual characters in `message` to their frequency, without any work on your part.